# How to use LaSalle principle for this Lyapunov (Hamiltonian)?

Tags: dynamical-systems, nonlinear-system, nonlinear-analysis, hamilton-equations

I am analyzing  this problem, and some questions has appeared to me.
1- In case 2 and 3, which Hamiltonian should I choose?
2- I did not understand case 4? Could you enlighten me please.

Let $\alpha$ be non-negative constant. Let $g(x)$ be a smooth real-valued function, and assume $g(0)=0$ and $\forall x \not = 0, \,\, x g(x) >0$. Let $G(x) = \int_0^x g(s) ds$ be one of the primitive of $g$. For an ODE $\ddot{x} + \alpha \dot{x} + g(x) =0 $, (x: real-valued). Set $y= \dot{x}$ and consider the ODE system

\begin{align*}
    \dot{x} &=y\\
    \dot{y} &= - g(x) - \alpha y\\
\end{align*}

Assume the following:

1)- When $\alpha =0 $, this system is a Hamiltonian system. What is the Hamiltonian $H(x,y)$?

2)- When $\alpha \geq 0$, show that the origin $(x,y) =(0,0)$ is stable in the sense of Lyapunov, by using $H(x,y)$.

3)- When $\alpha >0$, find a strict Lyampunov function and show that the origin is asymptotically stable.

4)-When $ \alpha >0$, can we show asymptotic stability of the origin by using $H(x,y)$ instead of a strict Lyapunov function in (3)? (\textbf{HINT}: LaSalle's invariance principle)

\begin{solution}
\textbf{(1):} When $\alpha =0$ the system is:

\begin{align*}
    \dot{x}&=y\\
    \dot{y}&= - g(x)
\end{align*}
The Hamiltonian must satisfy $\partial_x H(x,y)= g(x)$ and $\partial_y H(x,y) = y$. So we solve these equations and find $H(x,y)$

\begin{align*}
    \partial_x H = g(x) \Rightarrow H &= \int_0^x g(s) ds + C(y)\\
    H&= G(x) + C(y)
\end{align*}
and

\begin{align*}
    \partial_y H &= C'(y) = y \Rightarrow C(y) = \frac{1}{2} y^2.\\
\end{align*}

Thus, the Hamiltonian is

$$H(x,y) = G(x) + \frac{1}{2} y^2.$$
\end{solution}

\textbf{(2):} When $\alpha \ge 0$, the system is:

\begin{align*}
    \dot{x} &= y\\
    \dot{y} &= -g(x) - \alpha y\\
\end{align*}

First, we find the Hamiltonian to the system;

\begin{align*}
    \partial_y H=y \Rightarrow H =& \frac{1}{2}y^2 + C(x)\\
    \partial_x H = & C'(x) = g(x) + \alpha y\\
    \Rightarrow &C(x) = G(x) + \alpha x y\\
\end{align*}

So, the Hamiltonian is $H(x,y) = G(x) + \frac{1}{2} y^2 + \alpha x y$. Now, we have two Hamiltonians. However, we are going to use the one in case (1). We will show that the $H(x,y) = G(x) + \frac{1}{2}y^2$ satisfies the conditions of Lyapunov function. Define the set

$$\Omega := \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 ; |G(x)| < \frac{1}{2}y^2 \}$$

1- It is clear to see that $H(x,y)$ is continuous on $\Omega$.

2- $H(0,0) =0$, and $\forall (x,y) \in \Omega \setminus \{(0,0)\}$ we have
$$H(0,0) =0 < H(x,y).$$

3- $\forall (x,y) \in \Omega \setminus \{(0,0)\}$ we have

\begin{align*}
    \frac{d H(x,y)}{dt} =& \frac{\partial H}{\partial x} \frac{d x}{dt} + \frac{\partial H}{\partial y} \frac{ d y}{dt}\\
    =& g(x) y  + y (- g(x) - \alpha y)\\
    =& - \alpha y^2 \leq 0.\\
\end{align*}

So, $H(x,y)$ is non-increasing, then $(0,0)$ is stable.

Comment: The second $H$ that you wrote is not a Hamiltonian for the respective system: consider $\partial_y H$.

Comment: @RicardoBuring Thank you for your comment. So the second case should be solved using the Hamiltonian in the we found in the first case? And how can get restricted Lyapunov? What is the strategy I should follow to add more terms to make the Hamiltonian becomes strict Lyapunov?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, the choice $H=G(x)+\frac{1}{2}y^2$ is correct. We will use this $H$ below. Note that this $H$ is also a Lyapunov function and along the trajectories it holds
   $$\dot{H} = -\alpha y^2.$$
2. For $\alpha\ge 0$ we have $\dot{H}\le 0$ which implies the Lyapunov stability.
3. Try $\frac{\alpha^2}{4}x^2+\frac{\alpha}{2}xy+\frac{1}{2}y^2+G(x)$.
4. For $\alpha>0$ we have $\dot{H} = - \alpha y^2<0$ for $y\ne 0$, and by LaSalle, the system converges to the largest invariant set such that $y=0$. For this system such a set is the isolated point $(x,y)=(0,0)$. Thus, asymptotic stability of the origin.

**UPD:** Some comments on the Lyapunov function. So, we have
$$V(x,y) = S(x,y)+G(x),$$
where $S(x,y) = \frac{\alpha^2}{4}x^2+\frac{\alpha}{2}xy+\frac{1}{2}y^2$ and $G(x) = \int_0^x g(s)ds$. Note that $G(x)$ is positive definite by design, e.g., for $g(x)=x$ we have $G(x)=x^2$.

Ok, why $S(x,y)$ is positive definite? There are two ways to show that. First, note that
$$S(x,y) = \frac{1}{2}\begin{bmatrix}x & y\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}\frac{\alpha^2}{2} & \frac{\alpha}{2} \\ \frac{\alpha}{2} & 1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x \\ y\end{bmatrix},$$
and this matrix is positive-definite.

The second way is to write
$$
\begin{aligned}
S(x,y) &= \frac{\alpha^2}{16}x^2 + \frac{3\alpha^2}{16}x^2 + \frac{\alpha}{2}xy + \frac{1}{3}y^2 + \frac{1}{6}y^2\\
& = \frac{\alpha^2}{16}x^2 + \left(\frac{\sqrt{3}\alpha}{4}x+\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}y\right)^2+ \frac{1}{6}y^2,
\end{aligned}
$$
which is also positive definite.

Comment: How can I make sure that the Lyapunov function is always positive since we have the function $G(x)$ and $xy$ terms?

Comment: @FreeBooks See the updated answer.

Comment: Thank you so much. Now I understand. I confused with the function G.